# read data and reformat it, seperate by newline

Tags: c

The data file is consist of float point numbers, I want to reformat it. It has many rows(separated by '\n'), each row has many float number(separated by white space). For example:

```
0.0  3.14 6.28 7.12
0.1  2.56 3.45 7.11
0.2  2.22 4.44 1.55
```

The code I tried is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double num;
    FILE *fp, *fp_newFT;
    int index=-1;//t col

    fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
    fp_newFT=fopen("data-newFT.txt","w");

    while(fscanf(fp,"%lf",&num)==1)
    {
       if(index!=2)//!!!!problem code here!!!!
       {
           fprintf(fp_newFT,"%-14lf\t",num);
           index++;
       }
       else
       {
           fprintf(fp_newFT,"\n");
           index=-1;
       }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp_newFT);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0.000000        3.140000        6.280000    
0.100000        2.560000        3.450000    
0.200000        2.220000        4.440000
```

If I change the conditional line to:

```
if(index!=3)//!!!!problem code here!!!!
```

The resulting data is even more weird.

```
0.000000        3.140000        6.280000        7.120000    
2.560000        3.450000        7.110000        0.200000    
4.440000        1.550000
```

**What's wrong with my code, and how to fix it?**

Comment: What is the *expected* output?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read each line, then use `sscanf` to parse it.

Comment: Do you want to do something like: `fprintf(fp_newFT,"%-14lf\t",num);
       index++;

       if (index == 2)
       {
           fprintf(fp_newFT,"\n");
           index=-1;
       }
` ?

Comment: I just want the original data on ita own line, however each number take 14 character width

Comment: @HellmarBecker  but how this is different from mine?

Comment: Because it prints the number also when index=2. Your first approach skips that number; the second one prints it but gets the index counting wrong.

Comment: @HellmarBecker THANKS, your comment clear my confusion! There will always number not printed for my code

Comment: I assume this is a homework assignment, because you certainly *don't* have to parse the strings to floats and back to accomplish this.  If one input line has all the information needed for one output line, it's an easy task for something like `awk`.  Otherwise, you'd want to tell `awk` that each number is a separate record with `RS=" "` or something, and accumulate numbers until you had enough for an output line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is just re-formatting the text, you should utilize modulo  `%`operator to break the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    double num;
    FILE *fp, *fp_newFT;

    int index=0;

    fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
    fp_newFT=fopen("data-newFT.txt","w");

    while(fscanf(fp,"%lf",&num)==1)
    {
        fprintf(fp_newFT,"%-14lf\t",num);
        index++;
        if( !(index % 4 ) )
        {
            fprintf(fp_newFT,"\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp_newFT);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.000000        3.140000        6.280000        7.120000        
0.100000        2.560000        3.450000        7.110000        
0.200000        2.220000        4.440000        1.550000
```

Answer (score 0):

We still don't really know what you want to accomplish, but to read that data I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000

int main(void)
{
    double num;
    FILE *fp, *fp_newFT;
    char lineBuf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    if (!(fp = fopen("data.txt", "r")))
    {
        // handle error
    }


    if (!(fp_newFT = fopen("data-newFT.txt", "w")))
    {
        // handle error
    }

    while (fgets(lineBuf, sizeof(lineBuf), fp))
    {
        char* tok = strtok(lineBuf, " ");

        while (tok != NULL)
        {
            if (!sscanf(tok, "%lf", &num))
            {
                // handle error (bad input)
            }

            // do whatever you want with the numbers, here I just write them to the new file with fixed width precision
            fprintf(fp_newFT, "%.8f\t", num);

            tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        // add a newline
        fprintf(fp_newFT, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp_newFT);

    return 0;
}
```

You can then write it however you like to the output file. Remember to check the return values of I/O functions for proper error handling.